# Simulate browsing user

Tags: javascript, browser, simulate

I am developing a script in JS that for example logs in about 8 GMail's account and make some routines. To accomplish that I create a JS that opens gmail.com webpage in a popup (using window.open) and after that I manipulate the elements for example setting the value of login/password box, clicking LOGIN button...

So far so good. The problem starts when I develop a similar system to make Facebook comments. When the user types a link in the comment textarea the facebook demands that the user press the spacebar at least once to grab the link content and display the title, description and image. The problem is that is impossible to simulate the spacebar event using JS in a way that it works. I already tried everything and no way out.

So currently I am using an application running on windows named SENDKEYS that at every 20 seconds simulates a spacebar press in Windows and it causes facebook to request the ilnk inside the comment.

The problem is that I think it could work better. For example, is there any browser out there that allows javascript to actually send a keypress event? Or send a real click event?

For example: if you have a  in an html document and you want to simulate the "X" press. You can simulate it with javascript but the X will never show up in the textarea. You can fire kepress events attached to textarea but the X will not actually appears in the textarea. To accomplish that I need to use the SENDKEYS to make a real keypress while my JS set focus to the textarea right before the SENDKEYS press the X key.

It would be really nice to have a tool, browser extension or browser that allows developers to simulate user real events like typing and click instead of only firing the attached events.

Hope someone can help me! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you work out the HTTP requests that Facebook sends when pushing comments and then mimic them in AJAX?

Comment: It's a good idea but I would need too much time to study every website structure and API. What I gave you in the question is just an example, I have many scripts that simulates browsing in over 200 websites (posting comments, signing up, login...) and it's much easier to just simulate keypress and clicks than studying ajax requests, creating tokens...